# Element over element detection and events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl and it should detect when it is repositioned over some other element and than fire event. How can I detect whether or not there is some other element below the main one and how can it fire event binded to below element.

I need this to make a custom cursor for Kinect project.

Answer (score 0):

The event-firing part of your question is a bit unclear to me. I will still try to answer your question as good as possible.

The Control class has a property called Parent which holds a reference to the object the control is owned by (i.e. Form, Panel etc.). Your best approach would be to loop through the child controls of your control's parent and check whether at least one of them overlaps with your control.

```
foreach (Control control in Parent.Controls)
{
    if (control.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds))
    {
        // Trigger Event
    }
}
```